# Simplifying Laravel's updateOrCreate method for updating multiple rows

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm using updateOrCreate to update multiple rows. This could get ugly. Is there a smart way to simplify this or does the method provide a way to save multiple rows?

```
RequestData::updateOrCreate(['r_id' => $rid, 'meta_key' => 'q1'], ['meta_value' => Input::get('q1')]);
RequestData::updateOrCreate(['r_id' => $rid, 'meta_key' => 'q2'], ['meta_value' => Input::get('q2')]);
RequestData::updateOrCreate(['r_id' => $rid, 'meta_key' => 'q3'], ['meta_value' => Input::get('q3')]);
RequestData::updateOrCreate(['r_id' => $rid, 'meta_key' => 'q4'], ['meta_value' => Input::get('q4')]);
RequestData::updateOrCreate(['r_id' => $rid, 'meta_key' => 'q5'], ['meta_value' => Input::get('q5')]);
```

Comment: make your attributes fillable on your Model and then put your above code in Loop.

Comment: sidenote: if you are doing large sets, you have the option of going to "upserts" if your DB supports them, but you will be building those queries yourself and be locked into that db as the structure of those queries is db specific

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always wrap it in a for loop. Wrapping the whole thing in a transaction speeds things up as well.

```
\DB::transaction(function() use ($rid) {
    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
      RequestData::updateOrCreate(['r_id' => $rid, 'meta_key' => "q$i"], ['meta_value' => Input::get("q$i")]);
    }
});
```

Comment: why `$i <= 5;` What happens if there is 6th element in array

Comment: @usrNotFound there's no array, in this example we're just looping over the expected values (1 through 5). But yes, this simple example could definitely be refactored to a foreach as well! (via `Input::all()`). Even better to wrap the input values in another class though! (to keep the `Input` calls out of the database logic)

Comment: What do you mean by transactions speed things up?

Comment: If you wrap multiple SQL statements in a transaction, the database engine does not need to lock and unlock the table before and after each statement. Instead, it acquires a lock before the transaction, and unlocks after the transaction.

It's also just a good practice to use transactions when inserting sequential or related data. Either all fail, or all succeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am creating multiple records by checking if already exist or not. (Make your attributes fillable on your Model and then put your above code in Loop). 
**Just an Example code:**

```
foreach($user['did'] as $d){
        $user_did_settings = ModelClass::firstOrCreate(array('user_id' => $user_obj->id,"did"=>$d['did']));
        //$user_did_settings->view_incoming = $d['view_incoming'];
        //$user_did_settings->view_all_outgoing = $d['view_all_outgoing'];
        //$user_did_settings->view_all_incoming = $d['view_all_incoming'];
        //$user_did_settings->notify_on_incoming = $d['notify_on_incoming'];
        //$user_did_settings->notify_on_outgoing = $d['notify_on_outgoing'];
        //$user_did_settings->save();
    }
```

I don't know if it is correct way or not but this is how i create or update.
And see if it helps or not. In above example `UserDidSetting` is my model class which has a DB table mapped to it.

The method `firstOrCreate` will create new object of that model or give you existing object of the model from DB.

**Update:** (In your case)

```
foreach($request->all() as $key => $q){ //Based on how you get data (update please)
    $requestData = RequestData::firstOrCreate(array('r_id' => $rid,'meta_key' => $key,"meta_value"=>$q));
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: why not `firstOrNew` and save the extra query on the 'create' case?  `updateOrCreate` calls `firstOrNew`

Comment: You are right `firstOrNew` is better than `firstOrCreate` in my case, but this was old code that I had written when I was learning Laravel. Actually there is one more overhead for the DB and to ingnore that I should use `firstOrNew`. Thanks you noticed. Actually my model can only have those attributes which are inside the method thats why i used `create`